# Using a cookie and jQuery BlockUI

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup, blockui, jquery-blockui

I want to display a pop-up on home page, but only once. If someone goes to other pages and then comes back to home page, I don't want to display it again.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#displaybox").hide();
    message: $('#displaybox'),
        css: {
            top:  ($(window).height() - 391) /2 + 'px',
            left: ($(window).width() - 556) /2 + 'px',
            width: '556px'
           }
    });
    $('.displayboxclose').attr('title','Click to close').click($.unblockUI);

    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 30500);

});
</script>
```

Can someone help with inserting the cookie code?

I'm using jQuery BlockUI Plugin and jquery-cookie Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might be usefull for you;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if (!$.cookie('blockuicookie')) {
        // blockUI scripts goes here.
        $.cookie('blockuicookie', true, { "expires": 30, "path": "/" });
        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 30500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. The only problem, after the cookie is set, and the pop-up image doesn't show, it shows at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: I figured it out. I set 'code' #displaybox {position:fixed;width:556px; display:none;}

Comment: If a user solves your problem, please do not forget mark it as solved for future visitors. So if anybody encounter similar problem and come here they can easyly find same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use a jquery cookie plugin:

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    var caution = false;
    var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
    if (!caution || (name + "=" + escape(value)).length <= 4000)
        document.cookie = curCookie;
        else
            if (confirm("Cookie exceeds 4KB and will be cut!"))
                document.cookie = curCookie;
}

//name - name of the cookie
//* return string containing value
//of specified cookie or null if cookie
//does not exist
function getCookie(name) {
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var cookieStartIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(prefix);
    if (cookieStartIndex == -1)
        return null;
        var cookieEndIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cookieStartIndex +
                prefix.length);
                if (cookieEndIndex == -1)
                    cookieEndIndex = document.cookie.length;
                    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cookieStartIndex +
                            prefix.length,
                            cookieEndIndex));
}

function deleteCookie(name, path, domain) {
    if (getCookie(name)) {
        document.cookie = name + "=" +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
        "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
    }
}
```

To set a cookie call this way:

```
setCookie("dateModified","11/14/2013");
```

To get a cookie:

```
var lastDate = getCookie("dateModified");
```